# Is it possible to use variable with redirect code in Nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

In my Nginx config I have redirect rules like this:

```
map $uri $target {
    '/test123' 'https://www.somedomain.com/test456';
}
map $uri $target_code {
    '/test123' 301;
}
server {
    listen 80 default;

    if ($target_code = 301) {
        return 301 $target;
    }
    if ($target_code = 302) {
        return 302 $target;
    }
}
```

and it works well. But regarding of [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

I want make statement like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    return $target_code $target;
}
```

But during the restart, Nginx returns error `nginx: [emerg] invalid return code "$target_code" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Is any possibility to use variable in that way? Or maybe is other way to make it without any if statements?

Comment: Your linked document only relates to the use of `if` within a `location` context. And if you use a `map` you need a conditional statement to implement the `return`, and in vanilla Nginx that requires an `if` statement.

Comment: As far as I know only redirect URL or response body in `return` directive can contain variables. I think there is no way to get rid of `if` statements with this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see this that is [not possible](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.19.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_rewrite_module.c#L465-L481). What follows is the relevant part of the code:

```c
    ret->status = ngx_atoi(p, value[1].len);

    if (ret->status == (uintptr_t) NGX_ERROR) {

        if (cf->args->nelts == 2
            && (ngx_strncmp(p, "http://", sizeof("http://") - 1) == 0
                || ngx_strncmp(p, "https://", sizeof("https://") - 1) == 0
                || ngx_strncmp(p, "$scheme", sizeof("$scheme") - 1) == 0))
        {
            ret->status = NGX_HTTP_MOVED_TEMPORARILY;
            v = &value[1];

        } else {
            ngx_conf_log_error(NGX_LOG_EMERG, cf, 0,
                               "invalid return code \"%V\"", &value[1]);
            return NGX_CONF_ERROR;
        }
```

First it tries to convert the first parameter to an integer. If that fails it checks if that is an URL. If not, it bails out with the error.